# Annotating a timedelta sum with a filter

Tags: django

I have two models like following:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="events", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Category")
    started_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Started at")
    ended_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Ended at")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am trying to get total event duration for a certain period of time (like in last month) for a category.

I can get total (without specifying the period of time) duration like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta

from django.db import models
from django.db.modals.functions import Coalesce
from django.utils.timezone import now

Category.objects \
    .filter(id=1) \
    .annotate(
        events_duration=Coalesce(
            models.Sum(
                Coalesce(models.F('events__ended_at'), now()) - models.F('events__started_at'),
            ),
            models.Value(timedelta()),
        ),
    )
```

But as I said, I want to get intersection between this month and event durations. Is it doable?